# Proof Explanation: If $n$ is a positive integer and $a$ is relatively prime to $n$, then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I was reading a book about group theory and there was a proof given about Euler's Theorem.  Euler's theorem:If $n$ is a positive integer and $a$ is relatively prime
to $n$, then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.

The proof given in the book is as follows:

> We know that,  if $G$ is a finite group and $a\in G$, then $a^{o(G)} = e$($e$ is the identity element in $G$). Also, the numbers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$ formed a group under multiplication $\bmod n$. This group has order $\phi(n)$. Now , the group is finite hence, $a^{\phi(n)}\bmod n =1$ and thus, $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod n$.

However, I am not quite getting this proof . The theorem says any $a$ relatively prime to $n$ is valid and $a>n$, $a=n$, $a<n$ . But in this proof, we only considered $a$ to be the group elements i.e the numbers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$. How is the proof valid? Also , can $a$ be negative ? The theorem only states $n$ to be a positive integer and $a$ is relatively prime to $n$. I am not quite getting it.

Comment: If $A \in \mathbb Z$ and $A\equiv a\pmod n$ then $A^k \equiv a^k\pmod n$ for any natural $k$.  So the proof only *needs* to be done on $a < n$.  If it's true for all $1\le a < n$ where $a,n$ are reeletatively prime is will but true for all $A \in \mathbb Z$ where $A,n $ are relatively prime.

Comment: For any $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ there are integers $q$ and $a$ such that $b=qn+a$ and $0\leq a\lt n$. Hence $b\equiv a\pmod{n}$.

Comment: In general this is the *entire* point of modulo arithmetic.  If you prove something about a number $a$ in regards to congruency to $n$ then $a$ is *equivalent* to everything it is equivalent to and is for all intents and purposes regarding congruencies, it is considered to be the *same* thing as any number equivalent and proving something for $a$ is proving something for all $a + kn$ because $a+kn$ and $a$ are, with reqards to congrency *the exact same thing*.

Comment: \pmod{n} will produce the parentheses and correct spacing.

Comment: @fleablood so which means we proved it for all the numbers relatively prime to $n$ and less than $n$. , hence if we consider numbers $b$ relatively prime to $n$ and greater than $n$ then, $ b=qn+ r$. But if, $gcd(n,r)=d\neq 1$ then $d|b$ and $d|n$ and hence $d|gcd(n,b)=1$ , thus $ d=1 $and further $r<n$ hence $r$ is in that group and we know $r^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 (mod n)$ and hence, $b\equiv r=a(mod n) $so, $b\equiv a(mod n)$ . So, we can say, $b^{\phi(n)}\equiv a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 (\mod n ) $ when $gcd(b,n)=1$.  This proves it completely , right? Also can $a$ be negative?...

Comment: Of course $a$ can be negative.  You have a point the book *shouldn't* have speculated that $a < n$ without further stating that it will apply to all others later. ... your proof completes it, but IMO it didn't need completing.  If $a\in [a]_n= \{w\in \mathbb Z| w\equiv a \pmod n\}$ and $a^{\phi n}\equiv 1 \pmod n$ then $b^{\phi n}$ for *all* $b\in [a]_n$ and $\gcd(a,n)=1\iff \gcd(b,n)=1$ for all $b\in[a]_n$ [because $b\in[a]_n$ if and only if $b =a+kn$ for some integer $k$].  Those (almost) go without saying.

Comment: @fleablood Well, if $a$ is a negative integer and relatively prime to $n$ then if $a=kn+r$(e.g if $-3=8k+r$ , then $r=-3-8k$, which means that if $k=-1$, we get $r=5$ and $5<8$ and hence  remainder is $5 $) , we can still get that $gcd(r,n)=1 $ and $0\leq r<n$, then, again the same proof can follow i.e $a\equiv r(mod n)$. Also, $r^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 (mod n)$, then , $a^{\phi(n)}=r^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1(mod n)$, when $a<0$ and relatively prime to $n$. Thus the proof holds correct , right? ...

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Franklin Use \pmod{n}.

Comment: It's *much* simpler than you are making:  For any $a\in \mathbb Z$ and ever any $b$ so that $b\equiv a$ then the following two statements are fundamental well-known and basic.  1) $\gcd(a,n) = \gcd(b,n)$ and 2) $a^k\equiv b^k$ for all natural $k$.  Likewise it is basic that for any $a$ there is precisely one $a': 0\le a < n$ where $a\equiv a'\pmod 0$.  Thus it is sufficient to only prove the result for positive integers less than $n$ (we can ignore $0$ as $\gcd(0,n)=n\ne 1$.)

Comment: ... 1) $a\equiv b\pmod n\implies \gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)$ is easily proven any divisor $d$ of will divide any $kn$ for any integer $k$ and thus $d$ will divide $a$ if and only if $d|a+kn$ for all $kn$ and as $b=a+kn$ for some $k$, $a$ and $b$ have the exact same common divisors with $n$.  So $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)$. 2) $a^k\equiv b^k$ can be directly proven by noting $a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+....+b^{k-1}$.  As $n|a-b$ we have $n|a-b$.  Or we can prove it by induction from the result that multiplication holds. and that there is p

Comment: @fleablood But is my proof, correct(for a<0, as I did in the comments section ...)? Thanks! I do get it now...Thanks a lot!...

Comment: I already told you it was. But I also told you it was unnecessary to prove it.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks a lot! I do get it now...Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The statement is about $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$.  This is an equivalence $\mod n$ and all statements about equivalence $\mod n$ are equally true for any representative from the equivalence class that $a$ belongs to.  That is why they are called *equivalence* classes.

Review:  Given $n$ we can partition the integers into sets $[0],[1],[2], .....,[n-1]$ where $[k]=\{k+ mn|m\in \mathbb Z\} = \{w\in \mathbb Z| w\equiv k\pmod n\}=\{w\in \mathbb Z$ where $n$ divides $w-k\}$. [Partition means every integer is in exactly one of the sets]

We use the notation to mean $a \equiv b \pmod n$ to mean any and all of the following equivalent statements 1) $n$ divides $a-b$, 2) $b= a + mn$ for some $m \in \mathbb Z$ 3) $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$ 4) $a,b \in [r]$ for the same equivalence class $[r]$ (Note: we can notate equivalence classes so that $[r]=[a]=[b]$)

Now the key issue is that addition, subtraction, multiplication, exponentiation (but not division except as involves relatively prime numbers and requires a second introduction) are preserved by modulo equivalences.

That is to say:   If $a \equiv a' \pmod n$ and $b \equiv b'\pmod n$ the $a+b\equiv a'+b'\pmod n; a-b\equiv a'-b'\pmod n; ab \equiv a'b' \pmod n$ and for all $k \in \mathbb N$ $a^k \equiv a'^k \pmod n$.

Thus anything that you prove for any $a$ about $\mod n$, you actually prove for *all* $a'\equiv a\pmod n$.

And this includes relative primeness.   If $a\equiv b\pmod n$ then $\gcd(a,n) = \gcd(b,n)$.  So $a$ is relatively prime to $n$ if and only if $b$ is relatively prime to $n$.  Pf:  If $d|n$ then $d|mn$ for all $m\in \mathbb Z$.  If $d|a$ and $b\equiv a \pmod n$ then $b = a + mn$ for some integer $m$.  So as $d|a$ and $d|n$ then $d|b$.  So common divisors of $a$ and $n$ are *exactly* the same as the common divisors of $b$ and $n$.

......

To prove the statement:  For all $a$ relatively prime to $n$ we have $a^{\phi n}\equiv 1\pmod n$.  It is sufficient to not prove it for all $a\in \mathbb Z$ but to just prove it for *one* representative from each of the equivalence classes $[0],[1],[2],.....,[n-1]$.

That is because if it is true for one $r \in [r]$ it will be true for *all* $a \in [r]$ and and so if it is true for all $1,2,3,....,n-1$ where $r$ is relatively prime to $n$.  (We don't have to worry about $0$ as $0$ is not relatively prime to $n$) then it will be true for all integers $a$ in $[1],[2],.....,[n-1]$ were $[r]$ are all relatively prime to $n$.  That is to say, for *all* integers that are relatively prime to $n$.

......

Now the integers $\{k| 1\le k < n; \gcd(k,n)=1\}$ form a group under multiplication $\mod n$.  This is actually a simplification.  This would be true for $G= \{c_i| \}$ where each $c_i$ is *any* integer $c_i \equiv i \pmod n$ and $\gcd(i,n)=1$ and all $i$ relatively prime to $n$ are represented. In that case $G$ would also be a group.

Thus if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ then $a\not \equiv 0 \pmod n$ and we can make such a set of $G=\{c_i\}$ where $a$ is one of the members.

And as it is a group under modulo multiplication:  $a^{|G|} = a^{\phi n} \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is modular arithmetic, we can map any number to a number between $0$ and $n$, so every element of the group is *defined* to be in $[0,n)$. Therefore, $a≥n$ isn't part of the group. However, since $a \equiv b$ implies $ac \equiv bc$, $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1$ (mod $n$).

Comment: The point that is escaping the OP is that if we prove it for an $1\le a < n$ in the group, that doesn't seem to prove it will hold for the $b \ge n$ even if $b \equiv a\pmod n$.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that.